# AngularJs $http post before action hook

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Below is my $http call . Does angular has some function like **success**  say **before** which will execute before actual $http call

```
 $http.post(postUrl, $scope.tempData, {
        }).success(function(response) {

                alert(response); 

       }).error(function (errorCode) {

           alert(errorCode); 
       }
           );
```

Comment: Why do you need this feature?

Comment: i want to add a loader to page before the call and remove it in success after call !!

Comment: Look at this fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/dBR2r/8/ and search for angularjs ajax spinner. The basic idea is to do something in the requestInterceptor and responseIntereptor in $htto. Also see $http documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> Does angular has some function like success say before which will execute before actual $http call.

Quick answer: No.

But you can implement this module in `factory` or `provider` and implement any logic you want.

Here is example:

```
.factory('ajax_post', ['$http', function(_http) {

    var path = 'src/php/data.ajax.php';

    return{
        init: function(jsonData){

            // do logic here


            var _promise= _http.post(path, 
                jsonData
                ,{
                    headers: {
                        'SOAPActions': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems'
                    }
                }
                );            
            return _promise; 
        }

    }   
}]);
```