# Angular $resource pre-request task

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a way to have a $resource with a custom function which changes the passed data for a POST async before a request get sent.

```
$resource(env.SERVER + '/res/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
  test: {
    method: 'POST',
    beforeRequest: function (config) { return addAsyncData(config) }
  }
});
```

The interceptor property is only calling the response functions not the request once and I would like to avoid a global interceptor.

Comment: also relevant http://stackoverflow.com/q/19604057/4769440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't so far : the attribute name is `transformRequest`

```
'update' :  {method:'PUT', transformRequest:[function(data){}]},
```

Be aware that if you do that you will override the default one which is a call to angular.ToJson if the obect is not a file, a blob or formData, search for defaultToJson in angular source for more details.